# How to make the input file of my program start from the 3rd line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ash

I have a program that reads data from a file in this way

```
root@root# myprogram < inputfile.txt
```

Now I want my program to read the input file from the 3rd line and not from the beginning of the file.

I have to use `< inputfile.txt`. I can not call with pipe because of variable scope issues

Is there a way to do that in Linux?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure shell, no extra processes:

```
{ read -r; read -r; program; } < inputfile.txt
```

The first two calls to `read` each consume a line of input from `input file.txt`, so that they are not seen by `program`.

---

You can generalize this to skip the first `$n` lines of input.

```
{ 
  while [ "$((i++))" -lt "$n" ]; do read -r; done
  program
} < inputfile.txt
```

This becomes a little more readable with the use of some `bash` extensions:

```
{ while (( i++ < n )); do read -r; done; program; } < inputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe this will work for you (process substitution):

```
program < <(sed -n '3,$p' inputfile.txt)
```

Comment: or the "reverse": `sed '1,2d' file`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `tail`:

```
tail -n +3 inputfile.txt | myprogram
```

In bash, you can also use

```
myprogram < <(tail -n +3 inputfile.txt)
```

Comment: I have to use `< inputfile.txt`. I can not call with pipe  because of variable scope issues

Comment: @MOHAMED: There's always a way of solving the scope issues.  Please ask specifically what you need, so we can give a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this command: `sed -n '3,$p' inputfile.txt  | myprogram`